# Can't delete file (process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

Tags: c#

I try to delete files from a directory I specify. The first time it works great, but the second time it gives the next exception:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\DAAGEU\AppData\Local\Temp\Manual_Avatar\AdamBody_1K_Pants_Black_Blended.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

```
foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles((userDirectory)))
{
    try
    {
        //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        //{
            //fs.Unlock(fs.Position, fs.Length);
            //fs.Dispose();
            //fs.Close();
        //}

        File.Delete(file);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

It are only the images that seems to be "locked". I found some stuff on stackoverflow but nothing helped? I use some 3rd party software to generate the image.

Any 1 knows how to fix this or work around it??

ANSWER:

**I found the problem. I was using WinForms and in one WinForm I was hosting a WPF control with the image. I found out that I didn't dispose that UC after closing it. So my fault I should have mensioned that also in this question...**

Comment: Are you providing all code? Are you creating these images within the same code, if so, are you closing and disposing of streams or processes that create the images?

Comment: @ Daniel A. White, it's commented. @ mservidio the directory is being generated by some 3rd party software. And if I make changes I want to delete all files and regenerate the folder with the 3rd party software thats the idea !

Comment: Try one of file unlocker utilities (unlocker, lockhunter) to see which process is holding the file. If it's your application then there's more code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Run procmon to see what process has a handle on that file.

Comment: Don't use `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`, it's not only pointless, it also destroys useful information from the original exception (its stacktrace).

Comment: I'm betting it's your anti-virus software.  If you can, set up a machine with Microsoft Virtual PC w/o anti-virus software and test your application on it.  If it is the AV software, then spawn a thread to wait 200 ms or so and then delete it.  But one question:  If you dispose of your file after you create and then manipulate it, why do you not just use a memory stream?  Is it just for persistence between application sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete your file the usual way through windows explorer. If you get that annoying popup there saying Could not delete... It is being used by another person or program you can download **[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)** and have it tell you exactly which process has a lock on it. This little program has been very useful to me throughout the years. It even runs from a memorystick, so installing is an option. Installing it is definitely a plus though since it will automatically pop up with the name of the locking program when you get that popup.

Comment: I found the problem. I was using WinForms and in one WinForm I was hosting a WPF control with the image. I found out that I didn't dispose that UC after closing it. So ... But thnx for giving some great advice ;-)!